# Looking up a value in df

Tags: python, pandas, lookup

my goal is to do lookup for a value in a df.  For example, df:

```
Name   Item   Val1    Val2 
x       i      1       4
x       j      2       5
y       i      3       6
y       j      0       6
```

Let a be the value of **Val1** where `Name = x` and `Item = j` then `a = 2`.

Let b be the value of **Val2** where `Name = z` and `Item = j` then `b = 0` if it does not exist.

Any help would be appreciated.  :)

I tried to set Name and Item as indexes then use `df.loc[('x', 'j'), 'Val1']` but this gives me 2 problems:
It does not return a single value and does not give me `0` if the value does not exist.

Comment: Does this dataframe really have an multiindex or are these simply values in the dataframe?

Comment: These are just values in the df.  I just read them from an excel sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing your own function with `try...except`

```
#df = df.set_index(['Name', 'Item'])

def yourlookup(Name, Item, Var):
    try :
        return df.loc[(Name, Item), Var]
    except:
        return 0

yourlookup('x', 'i', 'Val1')  # 1
yourlookup('x', 'z', 'Val1')  # 0
```